# MacPorts Build of Gimp ends prematurely

Tags: macports, gimp

I wanted to install The Gimp on my mac. It's not in the HomeBrew tree, so I decided to install it with MacPorts, which I've never used before, and installed today just to build The Gimp.  I used the command recommended at http://alemani.com/installing-the-gimp-with-macports/ namely

```
sudo port -v install gimp +quartz +animation +python27 -x11
```

After more than 5 hours, I got this:

```
--->  Activating gimp @2.8.14_0+quartz
x ./
x ./+COMMENT
x ./+CONTENTS
x ./+DESC
x ./+PORTFILE
x ./+STATE
x ./opt/
x ./opt/local/
x ./opt/local/share/
x ./opt/local/share/gimp/
x ./opt/local/share/gimp/2.0/
x ./opt/local/share/gimp/2.0/themes/
x ./opt/local/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Nodoka/
x ./opt/local/share/gimp/2.0/themes/Nodoka/gtkrc
--->  Cleaning gimp
--->  Removing work directory for gimp
Error: Port + not found
```

and the job stopped.  Now, The Gimp is installed, and it seems to be working, although I haven't done any real testing.  But the verification that the website above indicates will happen never took place.

What does the error message mean?  Is there a way I can use MacPorts to audit if the build was successful, and perhaps to repair it?  Or, can I fix whatever was wrong and resume the build?  (I'm not willing to wait another 5 and half hours to get to this point, though.) Or can I say to hell with it, and uninstall The Gimp and MacPorts?  How do I do this? (I know there are pre-built binaries out there, and I would have grabbed one if I'd known the build was going to take so long.)

I really don't want to invest any time in learning MacPorts, since I'm happy with HoneBrew, so if someone can lead me by the hand, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates you had a space between `+` and one of the variant names in the command line you invoked. That likely means gimp was not installed with the variants you chose – you can check which variants were used by running `port installed gimp`.

Anyway, if GIMP is running as you expect it to, you don't need to do anything at this point. You can force the check you were missing by running `sudo port rev-upgrade` (and it will also look a little different from the output mentioned on the website), but it's really just a sanity check that should not find any problems.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Actually, port rev-upgrade found and repaired one broken port, so I'm glad I ran it.